# Ext.data.field.Date - alternate format

Tags: extjs

I have to consume an API that provides to me the same field in records in the same array in two possible date formats:

- Those where the second is zero will come in Y-m-d H:i format
- Those where the second is non-zero will come in Y-m-d H:i:s format

E.g.

```
[{"date":"2016-12-16 09:52"},{"date":"2016-12-16 09:52:02"}]
```

An ExtJS store shall consume such API. The field definition:

```
fields:[{
    name:'date',
    type:'date',
    dateFormat:'Y-m-d H:i:s'
    altFormats:'Y-m-d H:i' // <- how can I define this in an `Ext.data.field.Date`?
}]
```

I know there is a `convert` function, in which I can write some mess like this:

```
convert:function(value)
    if(Ext.isDate(value)) return value;
    var valueWithSecond = Ext.Date.parse(value,"Y-m-d H:i:s");
    if(Ext.isDate(valueWithSecond)) return valueWithSecond;
    var valueWithoutSecond = Ext.Date.parse(value,"Y-m-d H:i");
    if(Ext.isDate(valueWithoutSecond)) return valueWithoutSecond;
}
```

As can be seen easily, the field definition would be far more readable. Is such a field definition available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `Ext.data.field.Date` and override [`convert`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/src/Date.js.html#line99) so you'll be able to use it like:

```
{
    name:'date',
    type:'my-date',
    dateFormat:'Y-m-d H:i:s'
    altFormats:'Y-m-d H:i'
}
```